# Facebook app age restriction

Tags: facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

I have an app on facebook that is written in Facebook c# SDK and I need to restrict it to users above the age of 18.
How do I add age restriction to Facebook Canvas app?

Answer (score 2):

You can add restrictions via the application graph api endpoint:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/application/ (see restrictions section).

To restrict your app to users that are >= 18 use this call (replace APP_ID with your app id)
https://graph.facebook.com/APP_ID?restrictions={"age":"18+"}

You can find some more examples here:
https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/574/

You can also edit these settings in the App Dashboard, in the Advanced settings page for your app

Answer (score 0):

You can also add age restriction by going to the app settings and clicking Advanced.